# How to get output of a php file in separate html form at the middle of screen of lesser size

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to get output of a php file in separate html form at the middle of screen of lesser size. See tyhe below part. It is not working. Help pl.

```
 <html>
 <head>

   <script type="text/javascript">
  //This function auto-fills fields the form 'qform' and auto submits.
  function datcal(subnm, chpno, qsnno) 
  {     
  document.qform.subnm1.value = subnm;
  document.qform.chpno1.value = chpno;
  document.qform.qnumber1.value = qsnno;
  document.getElementById("qform").submit();
}

  //calling the function with some data
  datcal('chem11','1','2');
  </script>

 </head>  
 <body>


  <form>
    <!-- This is the other part of form here.....-->
   </form>



     <!-- I want to get the out put of below form at center of screen separately -->
    <form id = "qform" name="qform" action="getques.php" style="visibility:hidden"     
      method="post" target="_blank">
   <input type="text" name="subnm1" ><br>
   <input type="text" name="chpno1" ><br>
   <input type="text" name="qnumber1" ><br>
   <input type="submit">
   </form> 




   </body>
    </html>
```

The above code is opening a new window but i want the size of that window not full screen but less. How to do that?

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what it is that you're asking.  Can you outline the user interactions and explain what it is you expect to happen at each step.  Then can you explain what you have tried and in what way it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then, The easiest way would be to open create a page which takes all these parameter as query string. You can then open the new page in the window by making it a hyperlink. The new page can also process your input by taking all these parameter from query string.

```
<script language ="javascript"> 
    function submitForm(){
        var url = "http://www.newpage.php?subnm1="+value1+"chpno1="+value2 //and like this
        window.open (url, "acb", "status=no, width=960, height=700")
   } 

</script>


<a href="#" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</a>
```